# International Telephone Input as dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

International Telephone Input  is a good plugin. But it is just input. So user can modify after pick countries. I want to use it as dropdown instead of input 
so I changed this :

```
<input id="phoneleft" type="tel" tabIndex="-1" style="width:95px;" />
```

into this:

```
<input id="phoneleft" type="drop" tabIndex="-1" style="width:95px;" />
```

but this does not work.

How can I use International Telephone as dropdown instead of input like [this](https://www.enuygun.com/ucak-bileti/rezervasyon/?request_id=5564e0c22c935&trip=domestic)?

Comment: where did you find `<input type="drop">`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a select menu.

```
<select id="phoneleft">
  <option><!-- add your International Telephone Input data here --></option>
</select>
```

I  your example site, they are using list items.

```
<ul id="phoneleft">
  <li><!-- add your International Telephone Input data here --></li>
</ul>
```